# Coding New Trading Indicator

Tags: quantmod, financial, trading

I have a piece of code (below) that I am trying to correct. The goal is to check if there have been 7 consecutive positive days (close is higher than open). We will then place a binary value on the 8th day if this is true i.e. 1 if it is True and 0 if it is False.

```
seven.bar.buy = function(open,close,n){
  seven.bar.buy = rep(0, length(open))
  for(i in (n+2):length(open)){
  for(j in (i-n-1):(i-1)){
  if(open[(i-n-1):(i-1)]<close[(i-n-1):(i-1)]){
  seven.bar.buy[i] == 1
}

}
}
  return(seven.bar.buy)
}

seven.bar.buy(open = Op(EURUSD.st1), close = Cl(EURUSD.st1), n = 7)
```

The above code runs with no errors, but the output is a vector of 0's.

I think the error is coming from line 5 where I am trying to compare 7 consecutive closes and opens in a single if statement and then assign the binary value for true/false.

I know for a fact that 7 consecutive up days do exist in the sample OHLC data I have for the EUR/USD so it shouldn't be a vector of 0's.

Is there a way around this? Is this the only error?

Answer (score 0):

I made several changes to your code.
Please test my solution.

```
seven.bar.buy = function(open,close,n){
    seven.bar.buy = rep(0, length(open))
    for(i in (n+2):length(open)){
        if(open[(i-n):i]<close[(i-n):i]){
            seven.bar.buy[i] = 1
        }
    }
    return(seven.bar.buy)
}
```